# view path not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have this issue:

[image]

What I already did:

- composer update
- php artisan config:cache
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan view:clear (Here is the problem: `view path not found`)

Comment: sorry for that.... let's go; I'm using PHP with Laravel as framework, after delete one migration this problem starts.

Comment: Guilherme, you should use english here, or go to pt.stackoverflow.com if you wish to use portuguese.

Comment: Make sure you have these folders inside `storage/framework`:`sessions`, `views` and `cache` with proper permissions

Comment: inside `framework` I have: `sessions` and `cache`, but not view

Comment: add view folder and run again

Comment: Works! I added the folder and after `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: Good to know. I've added an answer to help people with same issue.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Make sure you have all these folders inside `storage/framework`:

- sessions
- views
- cache

with proper permissions

Comment: Worked after `artisan config:cache`